# if else statement and java script coding problems

Tags: javascript, php

My idea is the system will pop out a box and show yes or cancel , if cancel is selected then it would not store in MYSQL database,if yes then store in database, the problem now is it stores in database whether I click yes or cancel, how can i solve this ?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


if($favour=="Chocolate"and $topping=="Chocolate Chip"){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(window.confirm("You have selected chocolate's favour and chocolate's topping, are you sure?")) { alert("You have apply successfully");window.location="index.php";
        } else {
            window.location="customization.php";
        }
    </script>
    <?php
}

elseif($favour=="Fruit"and $topping=="Mix Fruit"){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(window.confirm("You have selected Fruit's favour and Fruit's topping, are you sure?")) { alert("You have apply successfully");window.location="index.php";
        } else {
            window.location="customization.php";
        }
    </script>
<?php
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO customization (cakesize,cfavour,topping, ccolor, cmessage,customizeMessage, C_date, Member_ID,status) VALUES ('$cakesize','$favour' ,'$topping', '$color' ,'$cmessage','$cumessage', '$date', '$uname','pending')");

}
?>
```

Comment: Don't mix Javascript and PHP, Javascript only executes once the page is loaded (client side), PHP executes before the content gets back to the browser. your MySQL query is executing way before your user even clicks on the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you have a problem, that is a mixture of JS and PHP, the idea on that code will not work well, you need to separate them. Do something like this: (you will just have to fit it according to your needs).

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    extract($_POST);
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $stmt = $con->prepare('
        INSERT INTO customization (cakesize,cfavour,topping, ccolor, cmessage,customizeMessage, C_date, Member_ID,status)' 
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    );
    $stmt->bind_param('sssssssis', $cakesize, $favour, $topping, $color, $cmessage, $cumessage, $date, $uname, 'pending');
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
        // insert success!
        echo '<script>alert("Success!");</script>';
    }
}

?>

<form method="POST" name="form" onsubmit="handle_form()">
    <!-- your input forms blah blah -->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function handle_form() {
    var favour = document.forms['form']['favour'].value;
    var topping = document.forms['form']['topping'].value;
    var message = '';
    if(favour == 'Chocolate Chip' && topping == 'Chocolate Chip') {
        message = 'You have selected chocolate's favour and chocolate's topping, are you sure?';
    } elseif(favour == 'Fruit' && topping == 'Mix Fruit') {
        message = 'You have selected Fruit's favour and Fruit's topping, are you sure?';
    }

    if(confirm(message)) {
        document.getElementsByName('form').submit();
    } else {
        window.location = "customization.php";
    }
}
</script>
```

> Sidenote: You are prone to sql injection, use MYSQLI or PDO and utilize parameterized statements.